# Configuration for HTTP Connector of apache tomcat server

Tags: http, protocols, connector

I am using **tomcat version 6**. I want to configure ssl by specifying some ciphers in HTTP connector . I am following below link which describes how to configure HTTP connector to prevent **logjam vulnerability**.

https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html

Before changes my connector configuration was like this

```
<Connector sslProtocols = "TLS"    SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" 
    executor="tomcatThreadPool" keyAlias="tcserver" 
    keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/tcserver.keystore" keystorePass="changeme" 
    maxKeepAliveRequests="15" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    redirectPort="8443" scheme="https" secure="true"/>
```

After changes my connector configuration is like this.I just added ciphers to it.

```
<Connector ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_25‌6_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WIT_RC4_128_SHA"    
    sslProtocols = "TLS"    SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" 
    executor="tomcatThreadPool" keyAlias="tcserver" keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/tcserver.keystore" keystorePass="changeme" maxKeepAliveRequests="15" 
    port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443" 
    scheme="https" secure="true"/>
```

But its not working.To make it work i had to change from

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" to protocol="HTTP/1.1".
```

But i want to use `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol` as it is non-blocking and more efficient.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: are there any error/warning messages related to this in the tomcat logs when you try startup?

Comment: No, there are no errors in server startup.But my configuration to prevent logjam attack does not work if i use NIO protocol instead of standard HTTP/1.1 .What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the logs of tomcat and i was getting illegal argument exception whenever i tried to hit my ssl enabled web page.
The issue was with ciphers. In **Tomcat 6** some of **ciphers** won't work if i use **org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol**. I don't know the particular reason of it.But the name of the ciphers i removed from my **connector** are given below. Now, i can open my ssl enabled webpages.If anybody know the answer please post.

**TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA**

**TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_25‌​6_CBC_SHA256**

**TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384**

**TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA**